# SQL Append criteria

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-like

I need to know where Xy Street can be found and I have 3 tables.

```
select t.nev
    from hospital.person sz, hospital.place t, hospital.member ti
where 1=1
    and sz.residence_placeid=t.placeid
    and sz.residence_placeid=ti.placeid
    and t.placeid=ti.placeid
    and t.street like 'Xy Street %'
order by t.street
```

Addresses can also be found in table sz and ti. My question is how to append those to the criteria (like union or something like that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should eschew using commas in your `FOR` statement because it makes the query hard to read, and this style of query has been deprecated.  Instead, use an explicit `JOIN`.  Regarding your question, if the other two tables also have a `street` column for the address, then you can simply add two more conditions to your `WHERE` clause.  Here is what your revamped query might look like:

```
SELECT t.nev
FROM hospital.person sz INNER JOIN hospital.place t
    ON sz.residence_placeid = t.placeid
INNER JOIN hospital.member ti
    ON sz.residence_placeid = ti.placeid AND t.placeid=ti.placeid
WHERE t.street like 'Xy Street %' OR
      sz.street LIKE 'Xy Street %' OR
      ti.street LIKE 'Xy Street %' OR
ORDER BY t.street
```